# Google BigQuery returns "Not found: Dataset nnn-business-insight:nnn_raw_harvest was not found in location US"

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm a bit stuck as the same query works outside a procedure.
Any bright ideas anyone?

So this works:

```
select * from `sps-business-insight.sps_raw_harvest.users` limit 10
```

And this gives an error:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
      sps.harvest_monthly AS (
      select * from `sps-business-insight.sps_raw_harvest.users` limit 10 
      )
```

Error message:

```
Not found: Dataset sps-business-insight:sps_raw_harvest was not found in location US
```

I have checked the structure of the table reference

Make sure your FROM location contains 3 parts

A project (e.g. `bigquery-public-data`)
A database (e.g. hacker_news)
A table (e.g. stories)*

and it works if it's not inside a "`CREATE TABLE`" or a "`CREATE PROCEDURE`" statement...

Comment: in ```sps.harvest_monthly```  is "sps" is a correct dataset ?